# Android Geocode Lag Issue

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

Whenever I use reverse-geocoding with the Geocode class to get the current city name the whole user interface freezes for a moment until a response is returned. How do I avoid this problem?

Comment: you may want to do that in a seperate thread not in the UI-Thread.

Comment: Do the geocoding stuff in a background thread (AsyncTask)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use an `AsyncTask`:

```
private void doGeoCode(Location loc){

 AsyncTask<Location,Void,String> task  = new AsyncTask<Location,Void,String>(){

   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Location... args) {
      Location loc = args[0];
      String address = "Unknown";

      //--do geo code lookup--

      return address;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String address){
      //--set some TextView's text etc.
    }

 };

  task.execute(loc);
}
```